# django rest framework serializers and django forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Question**: How to write DRY code for field validation in both form and serializer?

**Example**:
I have simple django app with model form, which validates `passengers` field for `Order`:

```
def clean_passengers(self):
    passengers = self.cleaned_data['passengers']
    if passengers > self.flight.available_seats:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _(u'''Passengers count can`t be greater then seats count'''))
    return passengers
```

And same code for validation in `Order` serializer:

```
def validate_passengers(self, attrs, source):
    passengers = attrs[source]
    if passengers > self.flight.available_seats:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            _(u'''Passengers count can`t be greater then seats count'''))
    return attrs
```

This isn`t DRY and I have write same logic twice. How I can avoid this? Maybe I can inherit serializer from form or something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use your serializer to deserialize and validate the data inside the `is_valid` method of your form.

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def is_valid(self):
        # Call super's is_valid to populate cleaned_data and do basic field validation
        valid = super(MyModelForm, self).is_valid()
        if not valid:
            return False

        serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=self.cleaned_data)
        return serializer.is_valid()
```

Comment: This works fine. thanks. But form errors is empty. To add them need to add:         `for error, value in serializer.errors.iteritems():
self._errors[error] = value`

Comment: Rather than using a private attribute, `_errors` you could use the [`add_error(field, error)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4de8aaf7ffc91b91cbb70e9db406abe9b160575a/django/forms/forms.py#L299) method.

Answer (score 5):

Here my implementation of reusable validation class for model forms. All native Django things are here except rewritten `get_serializer` method. Verified working state with Django 1.8.13.

```
class RestFrameworkValidationModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    serializer_class = None

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        assert self.serializer_class is not None, (
            "'%s' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, "
            "or override the `get_serializer()` method."
            % self.__class__.__name__
        )

        return self.serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        if super(RestFrameworkValidationModelForm, self).is_valid():
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.cleaned_data)
            valid = serializer.is_valid()
            self.add_error(None, serializer.errors)
            return valid
        return False
```

And here is example of usage:

```
class ExperimentForm(RestFrameworkValidationModelForm):
    serializer_class = ExperimentSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Experiment
        exclude = []
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting all validation (when possible) into the model (validators or `clean`).

`ModelForm` and `ModelSerializer` then use the mode-validation.

Comment: Thank for your answer but question was about forms and serializers in general. I used model form and model serializer as example.

Comment: Denis AFAIK, you can't perform single step validation at the field and object level when using Model/clean methods.

Comment: I also like to put as much validation in the model as possible as admin and serializer picks it up nicely. But once you need the request user it gets tricky.

Comment: Sadle they do not call `Model`'s `clean` method anymore: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3144

Comment: This answer is [entirely out of date since DRF no longer uses `Model.clean()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/7850) and skips that validation completely.